# Require modals doesn't work from another project folder Bootsrap 4

Tags: php, html, css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have product page `index.php` with many modals from Bootsrap 4 for quickview. Each modal has its own data. Index php path: `mykibble/index.php`, I tried to copy the code to `mykibble/women/index.php` and change `require` links to create similar page with different product cathegory. However, when I push buttons or click on href images nothing happens. Please help as I am running out of ideas

I tried change data-toggle and data-target to href and catch a click with jquery but I don't know how to show different data on modal as I just call a file.

I am really sorry for bad code structure(

index.php

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
require_once 'core/init.php';

session_start();

$a = 1;
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products where featured = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $a);
$stmt->execute();
$featured = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->close();

require 'head.php';
require 'timer-script.php';
require 'nav.php';
?>


<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>

<script> var x = 0; </script>
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php $tpi = 0;?>


<!-- Product cards with data-targets -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="rows">
    <?php while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)) : ?>
    <?php $product_btn_id = $product['id']; ?>
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="cards">
          <div class="img-container">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details-<?=$tpi ?>" class="image fit">
            <img class="card-image" src="<?= $product['Images']; ?>"  alt="<?= $product['Name']; ?>" id="images"/>
            </a>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="quick-view" id="<?= $tpi; ?>"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details-<?=$tpi ?>">Quick view</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php
  $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  //  SOME SQL
  ?>
<body>

<?php
// HERE IS THE MODAL THAT DOES NOT OPEN FROM mykibble/women/index.php
  require 'product-modal.php';
?>
<?php $tpi++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

product-modal.php

```
<div class="modal fade details-<?=$tpi ?>" id="details-<?=$tpi ?>" tableindex="-2" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="details-<?=$tpi ?>" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <h1><?= $product['Name']; ?></h1>    <!-- NAME -->
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <!-- Details of the product -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you check the console after you click on image to open the modal, does it shows any errors ?

Comment: bootstrap.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
%D1%82%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
IMG_20200216_002139250-800x800.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
(index):1 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/mykibble/women/product-modal.php

Comment: Could you tell why this happens?

Comment: first of all you need to check why the bootstrap file is not loading as it is necessary to open modals, and I am not good with php but you also need to look into the error which says Not allowed to load local resources

Comment: Oh, I see this is problem with running project in chrome. Thanks a lot for your anwer! I really apreciate it)

Comment: You're welcome friend